# I can't seem to connect an existing Sharepoint site to an O365 group

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have researched this and note the following:

1. I don't have the 'Connect to a new Office 365 Group" in the site settings dropdown
2. According to Sharepoint Admin the site is not already connected to a group and it lists the site template as "Team site (classic experience)"
3. I have checked the Admin classic settings and can confirm I have "Allow site owners to create new Office 365 roups for their existing sites."

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the modern experience, there is two way to create a team site, when you create it with in normal condition, an O365 group will automatically attached to this site, while the second way you can create a team site WITHOUT O365 GROUP !, so it might be that your site was created using the SECOND way.

Answer (score 0):

The site template showing "Team Site(Classic experiencce)" means the site collection is created in classic admin center.

It doesn't change though it has been connected with an office 365 group.

To verify if the site collection has been connected with an office 365 group,go to new admin center> Active sites> Office 365 group column to check the status: Yes or No.

And here is an article about connecting to new Office 365 groups:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/modernize-your-sharepoint-team-sites-by-connecting-them-to-new/ba-p/201371

Comment: Thanks Julie, in the SharePoint admin centre the 'Office 365 Group' column shows No. I checked the link supplied and it does not seem to address my issue.  Do you have any other thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Please try to connect SharePoint site to Office 365 Group using PowerShell Script in thie article:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connect-sharepoint-site-to-office-365-group/